# ExceptionMapper toResponse not Invoking while running junit test case. but is invoking when running through Client/Postman

Tags: java, jersey, jax-rs, junit4, jersey-2.0

I have a test case where am throwing exception incase of some basic validation. but ExceptionMapper is not being invoked. But if i run from postman to hit the service it is working fine.
Do Junit test have to run differently for ExceptionMapper ?

**Test case** :

```
@Test
    public void itShouldHavePersonNumber() {
RestAuthController controller = new RestAuthController();
    Response response = controller.insertGuid(null, "m012");
    assertThatExceptionOfType(ValidationException.class).isThrownBy(() -> {controller.insertGuid(null, "m012");});
    assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(Status.BAD_REQUEST.getStatusCode());

}
```

**Controller:**

```
@POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response insertGuid(@QueryParam("personNumber") Integer personNumber, @QueryParam("guId") String guId ) throws ValidationException {


        if(guId == null || guId.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ValidationException("guId is Required");
        }
}
```

**Exception Mapper** :

```
@Provider
public class ValidationMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ValidationException> {

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(ValidationException ex) {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(ex.getMessage()).type(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN).build();
    }

}
```

**Exception:**

```
    public class ValidationException extends Exception {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public ValidationException() {
            super();
        }


        public ValidationException(String message, Throwable cause) {
            super(message, cause);
        }

        public ValidationException(String message) {
            super(message);
        }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to annotate your ValidationExceptionMapper class with @javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you think the exception mapper should be called? It is not an integration test. All you are doing is instantiating the class and then calling a method. There is nothing magical in Java that will make the exception mapper be called. You need to run an integration test with the Jersey application running (and the mapper registered) if you want the mapper to be called.

One way to run an integration test with Jersey is to use it's [Test Framework](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/test-framework.html). Below is an example.

```
public class ValidationExceptionTest extends JerseyTest {

    public static class ValidationException extends RuntimeException {}

    public static class ValidationExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<ValidationException> {
        @Override
        public Response toResponse(ValidationException e) {
            return Response.status(400).entity("boo boo").build();
        }
    }

    @Path("echo-name")
    public static class EchoNameResource {
        @GET
        public String echoName(@QueryParam("name") String name) {
            if (name == null || name.isEmpty()) {
                throw new ValidationException();
            }
            return name;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ResourceConfig configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig()
                .register(EchoNameResource.class)
                .register(ValidationExceptionMapper.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testResponseOkWithQueryParam() {
        final Response response = target("echo-name")
                .queryParam("name", "peeskillet")
                .request()
                .get();

        assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(200);
        assertThat(response.readEntity(String.class)).isEqualTo("peeskillet");
    }

    @Test
    public void testResponseBadRequestWithNoQueryParam() {
        final Response response = target("echo-name")
                .request()
                .get();

        assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(400);
    }
}
```